# '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.2

I installed the DXA 1.2 JAVA web application on Tomcat with the `Create-web-application-staging.bat` script. Most of the site works, but the header cannot be rendered and shows an error message (see screenshot).

[image]

The logs tell me that something is wrong in the language selector.

```
2016-01-07 17:05:04,023 ERROR EntitiesTag - Error while processing entity tag
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 17 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/Views/Core/Entity/LanguageSelector.jsp
'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7
```

[complete log...](http://pastebin.com/WmgukYwm)

I am running Java 1.7 and I know that DXA is compiled for at least 1.7. The problem is in a Tomcat or JSP setting which compiles the .jsp to JAVA 1.6 profile.

**How do I get Tomcat to compile this normally?**

Answer (score 5):

Add those lines to JSP servlet settings in Apache's `Tomcat 7.0\conf\web.xml`.

```
<init-param>                                    
    <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
    <param-value>1.7</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
    <param-value>1.7</param-value>
</init-param>
```

[more...](http://pastebin.com/GaYhgv2n)

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11810014/1678525 and https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html

Comment: had been a victim & i was also wondering why does it say that i am using something below 1.7 when i was not.You should mark it as answer

Answer (score 4):

You're probably using Tomcat 7, which by default doesn't allow Java 1.7-specific stuff like diamond syntax.
It can be configured to allow it, though: http://censore.blogspot.nl/2015/04/how-to-set-tomcat-7-source-level-to.html

Comment: I came to the same conclusion 2 mintues earlier ;)

Comment: I do use Tomcat 7 indeed, this is the latest Tomcat version supported by SDL Tridion 2013 SP1.