# Setting up DXA 1.3 - Problem with Language Selector

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-java

I am getting the DXA 1.3 Java version set up on an SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 site and am seeing the following error message in the logs:

> Feb 29, 2016 9:05:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet DispatcherServlet threw
>   exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class
>   for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: 17 in the jsp file:
>   /WEB-INF/Views/Core/Entity/LanguageSelector.jsp '<>' operator is not
>   allowed for source level below 1.7

This seems to suggest that the Language selector is using syntax that's not allowed for Java 1.7.

The product prerequisites clearly state Java JDK 1.7 on this page: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v3&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-DD402008-D5C5-4DCA-A74F-893272D2B659&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-DD402008-D5C5-4DCA-A74F-893272D2B659.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-DD402008-D5C5-4DCA-A74F-893272D2B659

Does the documentation need updating or have I done something wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845372/why-operator-is-not-allowed-for-source-below-1-7

Comment: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13624/operator-is-not-allowed-for-source-level-below-1-7